# ArgoCD Your connection is not private

Tags: kubernetes, connection, argo-workflows, argocd, argoproj

I have implemented SSO login to argocd through Active Directory.
When I try to access argocd, I get error :
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from argo-cd.daa.pks.dell.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

When I check the logs of argocd pod, I see this error :
finished unary call with code Unauthenticated" error="rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = no session information" grpc.code=Unauthenticated grpc.method=List grpc.service=application.ApplicationService grpc.start_time="2022-05-02T02:06:34Z" grpc.time_ms=5.178 span.kind=server system=grpc

But when I open ArgoWorkflow and try to open argocd, it works.

Please help me in understanding what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a trusted certificate (by a certificate authority like letsencrypt for example if you want to use it on internet)
Example: (sorry it's in French but you got the point)

https://blog.blaisot.org/letsencrypt-wildcard-part1.html

https://blog.blaisot.org/letsencrypt-wildcard-part2.html

However if it's in your enterprise network, just ask for an SSL certificate from the authority of certification and use it. ( https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/tls/ )

You can also disable TLS/ssl to avoid this kind of error if you want.

Bguess